# How do I prevent my DIV from overflowing the table cell?

Tags: html, css

How do I prevent the div overflow that appears at the top. 
I do not want to set static dimensions either.

See it here http://jsfiddle.net/tok5zf35/1/ or below

```
.panel_white_black {
    border:7px solid #56575a;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    background-color:#56575a;
}
.round_all {
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.round_top {
    -webkit-border-radius:4px 4px 0px 0px;
    -khtml-border-radius:4px 4px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px 4px 0px 0px;
    border-radius:4px 4px 0px 0px;
}

<div class="panel_white_black round_all" Width="200px">
    <table width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding:0;" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="background: #353639; padding:7px; float:left; width:100%;" class="round_top">
                    <div style="float: left;"> <font color="white">{dialog title}</font>

                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;"> <font color="white">{X}</font>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="background: #FFFFFF; padding:7px;">{data here}</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `box-sizing` attribute:

```
.round_top {
        box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[Corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/tok5zf35/2/).

There's a good explanation on how this works [here on CSS-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/). Essentially it boils down in this case to that your `width:100%` now means *100% including my own borders* instead of the default *just my content*, which caused the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not aware of appending your code with yet another div - here is the solution

http://jsfiddle.net/my0j0mmy/

```
<div style="background: #353639; padding:7px;" class="round_top">
                <div style="float: left;"> <font color="white">{dialog title}</font>

                </div>
                <div style="float:right;"> <font color="white">{X}</font>

                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div>
```